# Subpage numbering on only specific pages in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, cc-2015, numbering

We are creating spare part manuals in InDesign where some of the pages are for only a few different parts where we want to change their page numbers as for example from 7 to 6.1 (because page 7 is originally a slightly changed version of page 6) and then continue to count the main pages from where we left. This is not applied to all the pages but just to a subset of them. Is this possible and if yes how can we achieve it?

Comment: Are you asking about the logistics of how to accomplish this task in a specific program, or whether a reader will understand the numbering convention?

Comment: I'm asking about how it can be done in Indesign CC 2015. I guess I should also add Indesign CC 2015 as the tag (if it exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this with section starts and prefixes.

Open the Pages palette and double-click on page 6 to make it active. Open up the flyout menu of the palette, and select **Numbering and Section Options.**

Leave the **Start Section** square checked. Click on the radio button which says **Start Page Numbering at** and put in **1**. Yes, one.

Under **Page Numbering,** there is a **Section Prefix** line. Put in **6-** or **6.** or whatever you want it to be.

This makes all the subsequent pages 6-1, 6-2, etc. or 6.1, 6.2, etc. as you prefer.

When you come to the end of the 6- pages, you click on the next page, make that a section start, and under Start Page Numbering at, put in 7.

(As a separate tip, if you find difficulty in printing or exporting a PDF because of the section starts, count your physical pages and use a plus sign before the number to indicate an Absolute page number. In this example, +7 would give you the page named 6-2, not the page named 7, because that could be 10 pages farther along.)

Comment: Many thanks. It worked but instead of changing the start section on page 6 I've did it on page 7 because that page was my first subpage to be numbered as 6.1.

Comment: Btw double-clicking on a page in the Pages palette doesn't bring up the flyout menu on Windows version of Indesign CC 2015. You have to right-click on the page to bring out the flyout menu.

Comment: @Montag451 Double-clicking doesn't bring up the flyout menu on Mac either. I'll edit to clarify. :)